# What does "Quantum shifty no-comply...." mean?

Tags: terminology, sentence

> Afraid I must take a detour. I’m going to crush Hiro, champion of cheaters, at the time and place of my choosing!! QUANTUM SHIFTY NO-COMPLY OF FORBIDDEN ENLIGHTENMENT!
>
> Ha! Typical! I land the greatest inter-dimensional trick ever and no one is here to witness it! Argh! All because of Hiro!

I understand most of this paragraph but the sentence "Quantum shifty no-comply of forbidden enlightenment!" It doesn't make any sense to me. Please explain for me.

The context is that he is skating on a skateboard in a hyper-dimensional pathway.

Comment: I would guess it is supposed to not make sense. Real-world context would be more useful (what work of fiction does this quote come from?).

Comment: It's from a cartoon. Is this the name of a skating trick or what. Do you know. Thank you.

Comment: No, I think the person writing the dialogue for this cartoon just made up something to sound fancy.

Comment: I'm doing the translation, so it's really difficult because it's voiced over. I need to find a sentence to replace that phrase. do you have any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense in English, so it will make no sense in translation. Just translate each element.

- “Quantum-shifty” — like a quantum shift [physics];
- “no-comply” — a noun phrase indicating non-compliance;
- forbidden enlightenment

Without *full* context, it’s not really possible to advise. The non-compliance could mean that enlightenment is actually reached (despite being forbidden) or the non-compliance could be that an expected quantum shift is not possible, forbidding access to enlightenment.

Without full context, I think I favour the first. **A quantum shift has allowed enlightenment to be reached despite being forbidden.** This is indicated by its being “the greatest inter-dimensional trick ever.”

It’s worth pointing out that *quantum* should be a minimal amount; but here it probably means a **huge change.** Simply put, a *quantum leap* is the [movement of an electron](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_electron_transition) within an atom due to a change in its energy; it’s shouldn’t be [a leap across the universe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Leap), although popular culture has made it that.

Comment: Since it's a hyper-dimensional pathway, I'd assume the "quantum" part refers to the physics concept literally rather than metaphorically.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helps. But if the native speaker can't understand, i suppose I should change it to something sounds fancy in my language.